# Characterization of topological space with a notion of "smallest open set about a point"

Tags: general-topology

Suppose, we have a topological space, where about each point we can talk of a smallest open set. That is, an element such that every other open set is greather than it in the poset of subset ordering of open sets. What would be characterization/interesting theorems of such a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a topological space, the condition "every point has a smallest (open) neighborhood" is plainly equivalent to "arbitrary intersections of open sets are open."

A topology in which arbitrary intersections of open sets are open is called an [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).

For example, the discrete or "indiscrete" topology on any set, or any topology on a finite set, is an Alexandrov topology.